# Controlling JCheckBox from other JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcheckbox

I am working on a `Swing` Application in which I need to uncheck or check the `JCheckBox` in a `JFrame` from another `JFrame`. I have tried multiple ways but was unable to do. 
Is that possible? My application is offline.
Please help me with that. Thanks

Comment: You will need some means of connecting the two frames. A nice solution may be the observer pattern (look it up), but maybe too complicated if you’re a beginner. Yes, it is certainly possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem. What have you done?

Common problems include:

- A tendency to subclass unnecessarily. The message seems to have got through for `java.lang.Thread`, but not GUIs for some reason.
- Poor separation of concerns (go for models straight away).
- Starting with the component and getting the model, rather starting with the model and constructing the component with that.

Here's an example of how you might do it.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(Example::go);
    }
    private static void go() {
        ButtonModel model = new JToggleButton.ToggleButtonModel();
        openFrame("Frame A", model);
        openFrame("Frame B", model);
    }
    private static void openFrame(String title, ButtonModel checkModel) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("Tick me!");
        checkBox.setModel(checkModel);
        frame.add(checkBox);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: both are defined in different classes in my case

Comment: @NancyFronze Why is that a problem? Pass the shared state (model) through the constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You can also control it through a button without problems:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Frames {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("Checkbox");
            JButton b = new JButton("Click me!");
            b.addActionListener(e -> cb.setSelected(!cb.isSelected()));

            createFrame("Frame 1", cb);
            createFrame("Frame 2", b);
        });
    }
    private static void createFrame(String title, JComponent b) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.add(b);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 50));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: both are defined in different classes in my case